# Selecting row as many times as it was mentioned in WHERE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

To my mind the best way to show what I mean is to give an example:

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE myColumn IN ('a','b','c','d','a','a','b') ORDER BY myColumn ASC
```

and results are:

- a
- b
- c
- d

but I want them to be:

- a
- a
- a
- b
- b
- c
- d

is there any way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Could you give the answer to Gordon. He got the essence right first, mine was just a syntax shortening thing.

Comment: I have given it to you becouse that syntax is important to me, it makes building query much much easier and more convenient. But, as you want, answer goes to Gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this using a `join` rather than a `where` clause:

```
with vals as (
      select 'a' as val union all
      select 'b' union all
      select 'c' union all
      select 'd' union all
      select 'a' union all
      select 'a' union all
      select 'b'
     )
select t.*
from myTable t join
     vals
     on t.myColumn = vals.val;
```

In general, a `where` clause cannot increase the number of rows in the result set.  It is used for *filtering*.

EDIT:

Some people might think that using `cross apply` with a values clause is easier:

```
select t.*
from myTable t join
     (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('a'), ('a'), ('b')
     ) vals(val)
     on t.myColumn = vals.val;
```

I don't have a strong opinion on which is "simpler".  The `union all` form is supported by more databases.

Comment: I known that where is used to filtering, but did not know how to show in other way what I mean ;) thank You for answer, works great

Answer (score 2):

As you are using SQL Server, you can use `values` to build your data as rows. You can then join to the main table, rather than the other way around.

```
select
    t.*
from (values
      ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('a'), ('a') , ('b')
    ) as x(myColumn)
        inner join
    mytable t
        on t.myColumn = x.myColumn
order by
    t.myColumn;
```

After editing, this is now the same as Gordon's answer, except for the using `values` which is non-standard, but more concise.

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae363/3)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm not sure what you mean. Check the SQL Fiddle. Ah, I get it, I'm not outputting the row, just the compared value.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Not trolling, just confused because there were no additional columns in the example table.